# I saw this in code to do with lists and I'm not sure what it does

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to learn from other peoples code and I saw this at the end of a list and could not find it anywhere I looked

```cs
List<IMyShipMergeBlock>[,] merges = new List<IMyShipMergeBlock>[3, 2];
```

What is `[,]` and `[3,2]` called and could you point me to where I could learn more about it thanks

Comment: It creates a bidimensional array of List<IMyShipMergeBlock>

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its a multidimensional array of `List<IMyShipMergeBlocks>`

The [3,2] is the initialiser for the array

so imagine a 3x2 grid and in each square there is a space for a `List<IMyShipMergeBlocks>`

EDIT: And important to note:  You would then need to initialise each list separately as with the above you have an array of nulls to start with

Comment: Thanks so much that makes so much sense also did not know you can do a list array

Comment: `there is` may imply that an instance already got created, which isn't the case. The array will be full of `null` values and each "square" need to be manually initialized with `List<IMyShipMergeBlocks>`.